# How do I assign value to the state in react while testing a component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using useContext to pass state in react app, I'm new to testing and I'm trying to unit test (Jest/Enzyme) a react component named timer.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { GameContext } from './global/contexts';


export default function Timer(){
const {timer, setTimer} = useContext(GameContext);
useEffect(()=>{
    if (timer === 0) {
         return;
    }  
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{
        setTimer((prev)=> prev-1);
    },10);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
})

return (
    <p data-testid="timer">Timer : {Math.floor(timer/100)}</p>
)};
```

I want to write a test for this component but i get error message:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Timer/>);
```

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'timer' of '(0 , _react.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your component with the provider for `GameContext`?

Comment: The code for `GameContext` and for your test that you want help with are not shown in the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @larz The application works on browser, I'm trying to do a test unit on this component which doesn't seem to work

Comment: @jsejcksn 
import { createContext } from "react";


export const GameContext = createContext();

Comment: As you are new to testing, I would suggest not using Enzyme, and instead use [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/). This will allow you to render the component in your tests, interact with the component (programmatically) in the same fashion that a user would, and query the DOM to see that changes occur as they should.

Comment: For tests, I write a Render component that I `render()` in tests. In these, I can wrap the component I am testing in contexts, setup useState as needed, etc.

Comment: @Steve-Cutter-Blades Do you have an example where you can wrap the component you are  testing in contexts, setup useState as needed

Answer (score 0):

Using React Testing Library, you do something like this to setup reusable test components. This is a very rough example of how I go about this, but...

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';
import MyContextProvider from './MyContextProvider';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

const Render = (args) => {
  return (
    <MyContextProvider {...args}>
      <MyComponent />
    </MyContextProvider>
  );
};

async function renderTest(args) {
  render(<Render {...args} />);

  const firstField = await screen.findByLabelText('Foo');
  const submit = await screen.findByText('Submit Button');
  return {
    firstField,
    submit
  };
};

describe('MyComponent', function () {
  it ('should fire some change', async function() {
    const {firstField, submit} = await renderTest({val1: 'bar'});
    fireEvent.change(firstField, {target: {value: 'blah'}});
    await waitFor(() => expect(submit).toBeEnabled());
    fireEvent.click(submit);
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.findByText('They chose blah').toBeInTheDocument());
  });
});
```

Comment: Biggest thing with testing and state is waiting for your DOM to be updated with state updates. In my example, the field labeled 'Foo' is controlled by state, the submit button is disabled until that field has value, so I can not click on the button until it is enabled. The 'submit' will also update state, adding some text to the display (in this case 'They chose blah'), so I have to `waitFor` that state update to hit the DOM.